# Date and syntax

Tags: перевод, грамматика

I have been told that the correct and preferred syntax is 11-oго while I have seen syntax written as 11-го. which of these two is most correct and most common?

Is this spelling correct: У меня день рождéния 11-го/11-oго июня?

Answer (score 5):

"У меня день рождéния 11 июня." or "У меня день рождéния 11-го июня."

"У меня день рождéния 11-oго июня." — understandable but wrong.